# Show where kids can transform into robots in a fantasy world

Tags: story-identification, tv

I saw a show a long time ago where a group of children (probably 10 years of age to maybe preteen) and they were transferred into a fantasy world (I don't know how?) in which they can transform into mecha (not pilots, but actually transform).

I don't remember the premise or why they were fighting except for a few minor details that can help narrow the options:

- There were two animal companions. One was a know-it-all who had a book of information, the other was dumb and would annoy the smart one.
- There was a green robot with a cross on his chest (?) that died but his spirit (?) allowed him to help the protagonist by fusing with him and becoming stronger after a villain tried killing the green cross robot and stealing his power.
- I know there were, I think, 5 main characters who could all transform into robots.
- Eventually there was an extra person who could also transform into a robot and was stronger then the protagonist but was eventually became good and could fuse with the protagonist to become a stronger robot.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)